# How do the ice particles interact to produce these magnificent halos?

Tags: everyday-life

[image]

I googled it and read the Wiki article,but they didn't give any details of its formation. So, I really want to know how these ice halos,that is recently seen near the Arctic, are formed.

Comment: [Here](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/halosim.htm) is a fantastic website on atmospheric optics that should give you some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice particles in the atmosphere deflect the path of light rays by refraction. Many ice particles are shaped like hexagonal prisms, and the most common angle of deflection through an ice hexagon is 22 degrees (there is a diagram on the ["22 degree halo" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22%C2%B0_halo)).

Most of the deflected light rays will not reach your eyes - you will only see the ones that get deflected towards you just as they meet the curved side of an imaginary cone that has its apex at your eyes. This means you see a circular halo.